# merge groupby series with dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Hello I have a `groupby` series and I would like to merge with a Dataframe so the product and time column being replaced in the Dataframe based on the `groupby` values instead of zeros. Any idea how to do it? Below is the series and Dataframes examples

original `groupby` series

```
Product       time           
Product1      2017-01-14 00:45:00       1
              2017-01-14 12:30:00       3
Product2      2017-01-14 00:45:00       7
              2017-01-14 12:30:00       3
```

original Dataframe

```
time                   Product1 Product2    
2017-01-14 12:30:00      0       0
2017-01-14 00:45:00      0       0
```

and I would like to combine these two to become

```
time                   Product1 Product2    
2017-01-14 12:30:00      3       3
2017-01-14 00:45:00      1       7
```

Comment: conidering your groupby object is named `grouped` , how does this work? `grouped.unstack(0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first unstack the series (I call it `s` here):

```
s.unstack(0)
```

which gives:

```
Product              Product1  Product2
time                                   
2017-01-14 00:45:00         1         7
2017-01-14 12:30:00         3         3
```

not far from your requirement.

If you want to respect the order and column names of the original dataframe, this one liner does the job:

```
df.merge(s.rename(None).unstack(0),
         left_on='time', right_index=True, suffixes=('_x', ''))[df.columns]
```

giving as expected:

```
                  time  Product1  Product2
0  2017-01-14 12:30:00         3         3
1  2017-01-14 00:45:00         1         7
```

Comment: thanks but it doesnt change the original dataframe when you merge with the unstack series

Comment: @goerge: If you want to change the dataframe, just use `df = df.merge(...)`